# How to use "COUNTIF" function to count one instance of something per row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question I'm hoping someone in the community may be able to help me answer.

Here's my issue, I'm trying to use the COUNTIF function to determine how many times a particular value appears. Easy enough right? Here's the tricky part, I want to only count certain values from each row. Only retaining the count for a particular value from each row. Per row there should only be a max of (1) error type counted. Screenshot below for more context.

Example

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show what you have tried and expected results for the above?

Comment: Can you make a helper column?  Insert a column between current C&D and call is something like "ERROR" or "MAX ERROR".  you can then put a formula in that column that can pull the max error from each row.  You can then turn around and build out the information for your chart at the bottom from the information in the error column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a helper column to track the highest priority error.  In your helper column use the following formula and copy down as required.  If you prefer a blank over the word none when no errors are found,  change "None" to "".

```
=IFERROR("P"&AGGREGATE(15,6,RIGHT(E2:J2,1)/(E2:J2<>""),1),"None")
```

In my example below I place the helper column in column D, but it can be any column.

[image: POC]

In D16:E16 I used the following formula and copied right

```
=COUNTIF($D$4:$D$13,E$15)
```

Comment: Thanks Forward Ed! That was a brilliant solution, works perfect for what I need it for. Much appreciated